# Make list of tables reference to start of table, while caption is below table

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, hyperref, captions, labels

I want to reference my table from the list of tables, but prefer to have my caption below the table.
When I click the reference in the List of Tables, it points the top of my screen to the caption, and therefore is the table not in my screen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|c|}
        \hline
  \textbf{TEXT}   & \textbf{TEXT}                  & \textbf{TEXT} & \textbf{TEXT}  & \textbf{TEXT}        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline        
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Week schedule}
        \label{tab:weekschedule}
    \end{table}

    \newpage
    \listoftables
\end{document}
```

Creating a `\phantomsection` above the table and then creating a label works for `\ref` but doesn't change anything for the List of Tables.

Is it possible to keep my caption below the table, but have the reference above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use package `caption` with option `tableposition=bottom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[tableposition=bottom]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|c|}
        \hline
  \textbf{TEXT}   & \textbf{TEXT}                  & \textbf{TEXT} & \textbf{TEXT}  & \textbf{TEXT}        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline        
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Week schedule}
        \label{tab:weekschedule}
    \end{table}

    \newpage
    \listoftables
\end{document}
```

or package `hypcap` with option `table` (and I would then recommend to also use option `figure`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[table,figure]{hypcap}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|c|}
        \hline
  \textbf{TEXT}   & \textbf{TEXT}                  & \textbf{TEXT} & \textbf{TEXT}  & \textbf{TEXT}        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline
             -        & -                              & -             & -              & -        \\ \hline        
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Week schedule}
        \label{tab:weekschedule}
    \end{table}

    \newpage
    \listoftables
\end{document}
```

See the package manuals for more information to the options and other settings.